# node.js requests returns doctype

Tags: node.js, doctype, namecheap

Im running a node.js app inside a namecheap dedicated server and im getting status 200 but the requests return a doctype html response instead of the actual data i need.

When im running the app in a local host env everything works correctly and i get the data as intended.

I didnt change any of my requests flow or logic when i uploaded my app to the dedicated namecheap server.

I get `!doctype html` response for every requests from the server.

Here is one of the requests:

```
  await Tokens.findAll()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("ALL tokens "+result)
      res.send(sendToClient(result, null, 1));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(sendToClient(null, err, 0));
    });
};
```

here is how the Tokens modal is built:

```
const sequelize = require("../utils/databse");

const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize"); // Import the built-in data types

const Tokens = sequelize.define(
  "tokens",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    symbol: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    total_supply: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    icon: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  {
    charset: "utf8",
    collate: "utf8_general_ci",
  }
);
module.exports = Tokens;
```

*** Reminder ***
The code works in the local host env

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: That's probably an error page, which you get. Please provide your code in your question. Or at least the error, which the error page contains.

Comment: So, you couldn't see, what the error is, that is written in the doc, that you get?

Comment: @Geshode No, i get only html file with no error.

Comment: So, there is no message or error written in the HTML file?

Comment: @Geshode no. just the website description

Comment: Can you post the HTML, which you get in your question?

Comment: @Geshode Hey ,  here is a link: https://i.ibb.co/DG5KbZf/Screenshot-2023-04-07-at-4-24-06.png